# How to pull request from repo X except for its latest commit?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I would like to pull request into `w35l3y/github-js:master` from `STRd6/github-js:master`, except for its latest commit [aa1ac50043b08b3cce8f947d4e2dd7082d26dabb](https://github.com/STRd6/github-js/commit/aa1ac50043b08b3cce8f947d4e2dd7082d26dabb).

It would be achieved if the option "Pull Request" was available when comparing [w35l3y/github-js:master...STRd6/github-js:19aeb84d0d1db1829624620342fe61e6f8c41644](https://github.com/STRd6/github-js/compare/w35l3y%3amaster...19aeb84d0d1db1829624620342fe61e6f8c41644), but it isn't.
This option is only available when comparing [w35l3y/github:master...STRd6/github-js:master](https://github.com/STRd6/github-js/compare/w35l3y%3amaster...master).

I know we should pull request between branches, but I always thought [19aeb84d0d1db1829624620342fe61e6f8c41644](https://github.com/STRd6/github-js/tree/19aeb84d0d1db1829624620342fe61e6f8c41644) was some kind of temporal branch.

All help is appreciated.